# Reading JSON file and convert into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I have a **JSON file** `data.json` with the following content:

```
[
   {
    "name": "Alice",
    "number": 10 
   },
   {
    "name": "Bob",
    "number": 20 
   },
   {
    "name": "Mary",
    "number": 50 
   }
]
```

And I want to read this JSON file and extract the value of `key: number` into an array:
`number_array = [10, 20, 50]`

---

Here is my way:

First I **read** the JSON file into a **string**

```
function readTextFile(file) {
   var raw_text;
   var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
   rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
   rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
   rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
             raw_text = rawFile.responseText;
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
    return raw_text;
}
```

However, when I call this function,

```
var result = readTextFile('data.json')
```

I **cannot** get the correct result but an `undefined`.

---

I am asking how can I read the JSON file and store it into a global variable (not only within the function local variable). Thank you.

Comment: Because your request is async (third parameter for [`open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) is set to `true`), did you mean to use a sync request?

Comment: @PatrickEvans - don't encourage synchronous requests - they're deprecated as it is

Comment: @JaromandaX, wasn't encouraging it, was asking if that is what they meant to do. As they might be purposely wanting a sync request fully aware of the cons against it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans - just as well :p

Comment: Sorry. I am new to Javascript. It seems like I should looking for the return value from an async function?

Comment: @Jaromanda X After looking up the answer, I still cannot find the way to return the value from async function....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite having marked this question as a "duplicate", I believe a few points are worth mentioning to the OP:

First, if you are using D3, there is no need of using `XMLHttpRequest` to get the JSON. D3 has a function just for that:

```
d3.json("filename.json", function(data){
    //code using `data`
});
```

Second, and the most important: why do you want to store the JSON in a global variable? There is absolutely no reason to do that. Once `d3.json` loaded your json, you can do everything inside the callback.

For instance, inside the callback, you can simply `map` your `data` array to get your desired outcome (once `d3.json` don't work in SO snippet, I'm using a variable here):

```js
var data = [{"name": "Alice","number": 10},
   {"name": "Bob","number": 20},
   {"name": "Mary","number": 50}];

var newData = data.map(function(d){ return d.number});
console.log(newData);
```

Altogether, this is the code:

```
d3.json("filename.json", function(data){
    var newData = data.map(function(d){ return d.number});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to store the json in a global var as I may have some manipulation on the data. I want to ask in line `var newData = data.map(function(d){ return d.number});`, I still cannot return `newData` to the main function variable, right?

Comment: You can do any data manipulation you want inside `d3.json`, and you can create how many callbacks you want...

Comment: I am very new to both d3 and js. Is it very common to have many callbacks in a function in js? And I dont understand what do you mean by `do any data manipulation you want inside d3.json`

Comment: `d3.json` will load your JSON and create an array (in your case) named `data`, or whatever other name you give it. You can manipulate this array any way you want. That's it. I advise you to study some examples, there are several good examples of code available, specially in bl.ocks.org

Comment: Oh, Do you mean I should do all data manipulation within `d3.json( )` <---function

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.